# Calculate number of alpha characters in field to a new integer field - ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

In a feature class field (screenshot below), I'd like to know how I can get a count of the alpha characters in each record and calculate it to a new field.  I have a "FieldCount" field that calculates the total number of characters in the ENGPLANDWG field.  I'd like to do the same thing but just for alpha characters where "F63Y" would calculate to 2 (F & Y).  I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is a question that I think you would quickly find an answer to at [so] because the part where you are stuck is pure Python.

Comment: If you try looking at [so] then make a code attempt here your question will be better placed for re-opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straight python, so would have been better to ask this on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), however this should work for you.

In your field calculator, select Python Parser and Show Code-block.

In Pre-logic script code:

```py
import string
def count_alphas(mystring):
    i = 0
    for char in mystring:
        if char in string.ascii_letters:
            i += 1
    return i
```

And in the expression:

```py
count_alphas(!ENGPLANDWG!)
```